# Dynamically allocating space for a 2D array

Tags: c

I am a novice C programmer trying to write a function that dynamically allocates space for a 2D array. I am getting a segmentation fault when running this code & i'm not sure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int allocate_space_2D_array(int **arr, int r, int c) {
        int i,j;

    arr = malloc(sizeof(int *) * r);
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
            arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int *) * c);

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                    printf("%p", arr[r][c]);
            }
            printf("\n");
}


    return arr;


}
```

I expected to be able to print out and see the contiguous memory locations of each spot in the array, but I am never reaching that point in my code, because when I run it, i get a segmentation fault. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Not sure why the formatting of the code got messed up. First time posting on Stack Overflow. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: There is a question on this in the C faq: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your program i see 3 errors one while you allocate memory for 2D-array,one while you're printing and another one is how you declare the function.
First malloc is ok,the second one is wrong cause you already allocated memory for r(size of row) pointers so it's just like if you have * arr[r],so to allocate memory correctly now you should allocate memory just for int and not for int*.
Second error while printing you put as index for row and column the values r and c,but r and c are the size of matrix , as we know the size of an array or 2D-array goes from 0 to size-1,in your case goes from 0 to r-1 and from 0 to c-1.
Third error you should declare the function not as int but as int** cause you want to return a matrix so the return type is not int but int**.
I change your code to make it work correctly,it should be work.

```
    int** allocate_space_2D_array(int **arr, int r, int c) {
          int i,j;

            arr = malloc(sizeof(int *) * r);
                  for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
                       arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int ) * c);

            for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                 for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                       printf("%p", arr[i][j]);
                 }
              printf("\n");
            }


return arr;


}
```

Comment: I agree with your remarks, but please note that there are other issues: the line `printf("%p", arr[i][j]);` either uses the wrong format specifier (`%p` requires a `void *`) to print undetermined values (the `arr[i][j]` are uninitialized `int`s, you may use `calloc` in this case) or OP's intent was to print only the pointers and the loop should be `for (i = 0; i < r; i++) { printf("%p\n", (void *)arr[i];}`. Also, what's the purpose of passing `arr` as argument (introducing a potential memory leak)?

Comment: You're right but i only correct his code in a minimum way just to print and allocate memory correctly.